# Area of Self-Intersecting Polygon with Repeated Vertices

Tags: regions, polygons

So Mathematica uses an even-odd rule for self-intersecting polygons, both when rendering them and when calculating their area:

```
poly = Polygon@{{0., 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {0, 3}};
Graphics@poly
(* See image below *)
Area@poly
(* 7. *)
RegionMeasure@poly
(* 7. *)
```

[image]

But the area calculation doesn't seem to work when one of the vertices is repeated:

```
poly = Polygon@{{0., 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 3}, {1, 3}, {1, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}, {0, 3}}
Graphics@poly
(* See image below *)
Area@poly
(* 13. *)
RegionMeasure@poly
(* 13. *)
```

[image]

I'd expect the area to be `5` as can be shown by *slightly* offsetting the points in the corner:

```
poly = Polygon@{{0., 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 2.999}, {1, 2.999}, {1, 1}, {2.999, 1}, {2.999, 3}, {0, 3}}
Area@poly
(* 5.004 *)
RegionMeasure@poly
(* 5.004 *)
```

It seems that the areas of the convex parts of the polygon are actually added instead of subtracted if I've got repeated vertices.

This looks likes a bug to me, but is it? Is there a fix other than applying random offsets on the order of the machine epsilon to the vertices?

Note that I am *not* interested in fixing the above example to a simpler non-intersecting polygon *unless* this can be done programmatically in the general case. I've only chosen such a simple example to illustrate the point. Assume that the polygon could be arbitrarily complex with repeated vertices.

Comment: If you use exact coordinates, `Polygon@{{0, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 3}, {1, 3}, {1, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}, {0, 3}}`, the computed area is `4` instead of `5`.

Comment: I'm interpreting your problem like this: "Given an arbitrary closed polygonal path, how can one compute the area of the polygon according to the even-odd rule?"  Is that correct?

Comment: @MichaelE2 `4` is even weirder than `5`. If I call `DiscretizeGraphics` first I still get `13` by the way. As for your rephrasing, yes, that's fairly accurate, although I'd like to stress that I'm not looking for general polygon area algorithms, but rather for a way to make `Area` or `RegionMeasure` work for general polygons (or a good reason why they *don't* work in the presence of repeated vertices). But it looks like your answer provides that (at least the former). :)

Comment: I realize what you're looking for, but I don't know how to achieve it without some intervention (as in my answer). BTW, the 4 seems to be the area of the excluded square, as if it got the even-odd rule **backwards**; the 13 can be obtained by double-counting the excluded square.  At this point, that seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could triangulate the polygon, pick out the triangles inside the polygon, and compute their area.

```
area[poly_Polygon] := 
 With[{mpoly = TriangulateMesh[DiscretizeGraphics[poly], 
                 "MaxCellMeasure" -> Area@Graphics`Mesh`BoundingAxisAlignedRectangle[poly]]},
  With[{pts = MeshCoordinates[mpoly],
        tri = MeshCells[mpoly, 2]},
   Area@MeshRegion[
     pts,
     Pick[
      tri, 
      tri /. Polygon[v_] :> 
        Graphics`PolygonUtils`InPolygonQ[poly, Mean[pts[[v]]]]
      ]
     ]
   ]]

poly = Polygon@{{0., 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 3}, {1, 3}, {1, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}, {0, 3}};
area[poly]
(*  5.  *)

poly2 = Polygon@{{0., 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {0, 3}};
area[poly2]
(*  7.  *)
```

---

Response to comment:  Bug indeed!!!  (I'm using V10.0.2, OSX 10.10.2.; reported to Wolfram Support.)

```
DiscretizeRegion[
 Polygon@N@{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 2}, {1, 0}, {0, 2}}, 
 Method -> "RegionPlot"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that

```
RegionPlot[Polygon@N@{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 2}, {1, 0}, {0, 2}}]
```

works fine.

Comment: I'm accepting this, because it does indeed provide a general workaround. That being said, I'd still be interested in why `Area` and `RegionMeasure` can't handle this as they handle any other self-intersecting polygon, so if someone has an answer for that, please do post it.

Comment: It seems that this runs into problems if a vertex coincides with another edge of the polygon. Try `Polygon@N@{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 2}, {1, 0}, {0, 2}}`.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Please see my update.

Comment: Re your bug report, 10.3 doesn't respond with an internal error any more but simply `DiscretizeRegion::drf: DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region [...]`

Answer (score 4):

I think it could probably issue a message. Perhaps you could report that to the technical service.

If you use the coordinates in an order

```
mr = DiscretizeGraphics[
  Polygon[{{0., 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 3}, {0, 3}}]];

Area[mr]
```

things work as expected.

To check if coordinates have duplicates one can use

```
{coords, map} = 
 Region`Mesh`DeleteDuplicateCoordinates[{{0., 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 3}, {1, 
    3}, {1, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}, {0, 3}}]
{{{0.`, 0.`}, {3.`, 0.`}, {3.`, 3.`}, {1.`, 3.`}, {1.`, 1.`}, {3.`, 
   1.`}, {0.`, 3.`}}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7}}
```

This returns the coordinates without the duplicates and an incidence map. In the case there are no duplicates then the map is the `Indentity`. You could check for that. But again, the coordinate specification needs to be encircle the area in an systematic way.

Comment: Of course, the first example is no longer self-intersecting, whereas the second gives a completely different polygon than the one I'm interested. Ideally I'd be looking for a general way to deal with the self-intersecting ones without having to analyse them for an equivalent polygon without self-intersections (which may be a nontrivial task to begin with).

Comment: @MartinBüttner, I think it were good if you clarified your questions. Is it a bug: No, more of a messaging issue, what's a fix: give coordinates in a proper manner. If you want something else, it might help explaining that in the question. Concerning the second example: this was to demonstrate how you detect duplicate coordinates. The incidence map is not the new polygon. It's mapping incidences of, say, a `GraphicsComplex` to the new order. But you do not have that here.